# Stripe javascript API Stripe.Recipients undefined

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, stripe-payments

so I'm using Parse to handle a Stripe enabled app. We want our users to be able to cash out their in app credits, and we're planning on using Stripe to handle that. I've been able to create Customers in Stripe successfully, and link a bank account to these. Now I'm trying to initiate a transfer to one of these bank accounts, following

```
https://stripe.com/docs/tutorials/sending-transfers
```

But I'm running into an issue where `Stripe.recipients` is undefined.

Relevant code:

Initialization of Stripe:

```
var Stripe = require('stripe');
Stripe.initialize('sk_test_ukk7e8B46I39nxoUd6XILpPZ');
```

Parse Cloud Function for transferring:

```
  Parse.Cloud.define("startTransfer", function(request, response) {
    var userObjectId = request.params.userObjectId;
    var credits = request.params.credits;
    var StripeCustomer = Parse.Object.extend("StripeCustomer");
    var stripeCustomerQuery = new Parse.Query(StripeCustomer);

    stripeCustomerQuery.equalTo("userObj", userObjectId);
    stripeCustomerQuery.find({
      success: function(results) {
        if(results.length == 0) {

        } else if(results.length == 1) {
          var customer = results[0];
          // handle returning customer adding a new card
          Stripe.Recipients.create({
            name: customer.description,
            type: "individual",
            bank_account: customer.source,
            email: customer.email
          }, function(err, recipient) {
            // recipient;
            console.log("have a recipient");
            if(err == nil) {
              Stripe.transfers.create({
              amount: credits,
              currency: "usd",
              recipient: recipient,
              bank_account: customer.source,
              statement_descriptor: "Cash Out"
              }, function(err1, transfer) {
                // asynchronously called
                if(err == nil) {
                   response.success("Successfully transferred funds");
                } else {
                  response.error(err1);
                }
              });
            } else {
            response.error(err);
            }
          });
        }
      }, error: function(error) {
          reponse.error(error);          
      }
    });
  });
```

I'm calling this from iOS, using the PFCloud.callFunction API call. It seems to be hitting this code properly, but Recipients is said to be undefined in the error message, but the Stripe documentation requires it. How can I solve this?

Comment: Parse developed its own Stripe library (its currently using an api version from about 2 years ago). So the Stripe Node.js api docs would not be applicable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, the Stripe cloud code module is indeed using an older version of Stripe. Therefore, according to this bug report, the solution is to download the newer SDK and manually add it to cloud code modules.

Source:

```
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/523104684492016/
```

Actual post from the bug report (from Facebook employee):

```
Parse modules are using an old version of the API and there is no plan to update it in the near future.

As a workaround please download the newer SDKs directly off the third party site, place it in "cloud/" folder and import it using require();

We're going to close this by design.
```